# Paperback bought in 1980s about a higher being who has brought aliens from all walks of life to see who will get to utopia or Eden

Tags: story-identification, books

I picked this paperback in the 1980s in a second hand bookshop but can't remember the name.

It starts with a group of teenagers going to a disco. The floor then dissolves and they wake up on a different planet run by a higher being who has brought aliens from all walks of life to see who will get to utopia or Eden. I remember the box man character who enticed beings to enter his box so he can eat them.

I remember the book had a purple cover. Also the Earth was blown up that's why the chosen teenagers ended up on the planet. Other than the box man I cannot remember a thing it's a shot in the dark but I'm guessing with the word disco rather than discoteque then late 70s early 80s.

Comment: Yopu have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, you say you bought this in the 80s but do you know when it likely came out? Can you remember any character names or specific plot elements further to the generic overview you have given here?

Comment: I remember the book had a purple cover. Also the earth was blown up that's why the chosen teenagers ended up on the planet. Other than the box man I cannot remember a thing it's a shot in the dark but I'm guessing with the word disco rather than discoteque then late 70s early 80s. Sorry this is all I have. Just on my bucket list to read again. I found the spider world series which was another on my list all paperbacks. Brilliant series.